# Titanium mobile Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, titanium-mobile

Ok so I'm new to Titanium and I'm pretty much a noob at Javascript

I tried doing this:

```
app.view.newMatrix = function() {
return {
    matrix = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
        title:'Add a New Matrix',
        backgroundColor:'stripped',
        navBarHidden: false
    }),     
    // navbar buttons
    cancel = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        title:'Cancel'
    }),
    save = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        title:'Save',
        style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.SAVE
    }),
    name_label = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        text: "Matrix Name:",
        font: { fontsize: 12, fontstyle: 'italic', color: '#336699' },
        height: 35,
        top: 35,
        left: 30,
        width: 150,
        color: "black"
    }),
    name = Titanium.UI.createTextArea({
        color: '#336699',
        height: this.name_label.height,
        top: this.name_label.top + 35,
        left: this.name_label.left - 10,
        width: 275,
        borderRadius:15
    }),
    setItems = function() {
        this.win.add(this.name);
        this.win.add(this.name_label);
        this.win.add(this.desc);
        this.win.add(this.desc_label);
        Ti.API.info("label:"+ this.name_label.height);
        return this.win.open({modal: true, animation: true});  
    }
}
```

}

then called it like this:

```
app.controller.home = function() {
        var home = app.view.home();
        home.setItems();

        home.butn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            app.controller.newMatrix();
        });

        home.butn2.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            matrix_table(tab);
        });

        home.butn3.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            newItem();
        });

        home.butn5.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            item_table(); 
        });
```

}

I did this because I saw a Titanium MVC suggestion here but I don't get why it returns an anonymous object. I can't access properties like `name_label` from within the `name` object.
I figured out that I should do this instead:

```
app.view.newMatrix = function() {
    this.matrix = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
        title:'Add a New Matrix',
        backgroundColor:'stripped',
        navBarHidden: false
    }), 
    // navbar buttons
    this.cancel = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        title:'Cancel'
    }),

    this.save = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        title:'Save',
        style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.SAVE
    }),

    this.name_label = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        text: "Matrix Name:",
        font: { fontsize: 12, fontstyle: 'italic', color: '#336699' },
        height: 35,
        top: 35,
        left: 30,
        width: 150,
        color: "black"
    }),

    this.name = Titanium.UI.createTextArea({
        color: '#336699',
        height: this.name_label.height,
        top: this.name_label.top + 35,
        left: this.name_label.left - 10,
        width: 275,
        borderRadius:15
    }),

    this.setItems = function() {
        this.win.add(this.name);
        this.win.add(this.name_label);
        this.win.add(this.desc);
        this.win.add(this.desc_label);
        Ti.API.info("label:"+ this.name_label.height);
        return this.win.open({modal: true, animation: true});  
    }
```

}

and call it like this:

```
app.controller.home = function() {
return {
    getView: function() {

        var home = app.view.home();
        home.setItems();

        home.butn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            app.controller.newMatrix();
        });

        home.butn2.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            matrix_table(tab);
        });

        home.butn3.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            newItem();
        });

        home.butn5.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            item_table(); 
        });
    }
}
```

}

But I don't know why the first example doesn't work. I mean aren't properties the same as variables? Also I do know that the second example is an object too.. is that how I'm supposed to do them? Also with the second example is the `new` keyword optional? Should I use it? I kinda wanted to stay away from that cause I'm not sure when I should use it.

thanks I hope I made sense. I do have it working but I don't know if the second example is the right way to go....